How to allow specific IPs and deny all on nginx?
I am running docker containers on windows local PC.
and set port forwarding on my local router to enable external entering.
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is below.
I tried allow xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; and deny all;. But not worked
Now I am using if statements to allow specific IPs. But not work too.
I want to allow IPs to enter to specific url path.
How to fix it?
upstream django_server {
    server host.docker.internal:8888;
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        set $allow false;
        if ($http_x_forwarded_for ~ "172\.18\.0\.1?$") {
            set $allow true;
        }
        if ($http_x_forwarded_for ~ "127\.0\.0\.1?$") {
            set $allow true;
        }
        if ($http_x_forwarded_for ~ "127.0.0.1?$") {
            set $allow true;
        }
        if ($allow = false) {
            return 403;
        }

        proxy_pass http://django_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}


I used geo to allow specific IPs.
But I can access the url by cell phone IP that not wrote on geo $allow.
updated
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    upstream django_server {
        server host.docker.internal:8888;
    }

    geo $allow {
        default 0;
        127.0.0.1 1;
        172.18.0.1 1;
        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;
        listen [::]:8080;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

        if ($allow = 0) {
            return 403;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://django_server;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }
}


You can use the ngx_http_geo_module module.
Example:
http {

    geo $deny {
        default         1;
        proxy           172.18.0.0/24;
        1.2.3.0/24      0;
        2.2.2.2         0;
    }

    server {

        if ($deny) {
            return 403 'access denied';
        }

        location / {
            # ...
        }

    }

Here we use geo to map a remote IP to the $deny variable value. By default, geo uses $remote_addr, but you can instruct it to use any variable instead or to use the X-Forwarded-For header if it set by a trusted proxy. We use the latter — proxy 172.18.0.0/24 means “trust X-Forwarded-For if it comes from any IP in range 172.18.0.xxx” (given that our ingress proxy has an IP in that range), then we allow (that is, set $deny to 0) any IP in range 1.2.3.xxx and only 2.2.2.2, any other IP is mapped to 1 by default.

Hello
I updated my nginx.conf with geo, and I can access on my cell phone. I want to allow only specific IPs. You can see my updated .conf on the body of my question.

I checked access.log and client ip is always 172.18.0.1. 172.18.0.1 is docker bridge network ip maybe. how to get pure client IP?


Don't you have a reverse proxy in front of nginx container? My answer assumes you have some kind of ingress proxy that adds X-Forwarded-For. 2. What network mode do you use for nginx containter, is it bridge?

